# Why does slice::binary_search return an incorrect result?

Tags: rust

In the program below `binary_search` returns `Err(2)` rather than the expected `Ok(0)`. Is this a bug?

```
fn main() {
    let x = vec!["slot", "s"];
    let u =  x.binary_search(&"slot");
    println!("{:?}", u);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No**.

`binary_search` expects a *sorted* input, but you provided a randomly ordered one.

As is famously attribute to Charles Babbage: *Garbage in, garbage out*.

*Note: in C++, I've had crashes executing binary search on non-sorted output, you're lucky it's Rust ;)*

Comment: How... how would unsorted data cause a crash? I can understand returning the wrong value, or *maybe* even an infinite loop, but a **crash**?

Comment: @Shepmaster: Reading out of bounds... causing a segmentation fault.

Comment: That sounds more like the length of the array was misrepresented, not just that the data wasn't sorted?

Comment: @Shepmaster: no, it really was a sorting issue. I've also had the issue with `std::sort` being passed an incorrect sorting predicate. The algorithms sometimes assume that given the pre-conditions there *must* be a next element, and access it without actually checking whether there is one or not given the range of iterators given.

Comment: @MatthieuM I've actually made this exact mistake when implementing a sorting algorithm in Rust. These bounds checks can actually cause a not-insignificant performance loss for correct comparators. I think there's been some discussion around a `unsafe trait TrustedOrd` in Rust, for types with known-correct `Ord` implementations.